# Are there places with water hardness between 30 dGH and 50 dGH?

Tags: water

In the manual of my new dishwasher there is a table of values of water hardness. It goes until 50 dGH (degrees of general hardness) which corresponds to 9,0 mmol/l in the same table.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DGH):

> 1 dGH is equivalent to 0.17832 mmol per litre of elemental calcium
>   and/or magnesium ions

The interesting thing is that 6 out of the 10 options for water softener levels are for water hardness greater than 19 dGH and most websites consider 20 dGH as very hard water already.

I couldn't' find any world map or regional map from any place containing dGH values greater than 20. I was wondering whether water hardness levels between 20/30 and 50 are commonplace somewhere in the world.

Comment: Try lookin at hot spring where hte mineral content is at saturation.